# How to see the obstacles ahead when moving at the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Imagine we're operating a space vehicle that moves at the speed of light.

How can we set up our route based on the obstacles ahead?

We need to send some sort of signal to see if there's anything in front of us and collect the reflections from the objects. However, moving at the speed of light, we will be traveling with the signal.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, that you cannot be traveling with the speed of light because your mass is not zero.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass . A mass defined in its rest frame with some value, if moved with the velocity of light the relativistic mass would be infinite .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could travel at the speed of light (which you can't) length contraction would mean all of space would flatten into a single plane. This can be seen from the length contraction formula $$L_{\text{obs}}=L_{\text{reference}}\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
where $L_{\text{obs}}$ is the length you would observe going at the speed $v$ wrt a reference frame in which the object has length $L_{\text{reference}}$. As can be seen from the above equation as $v\rightarrow c$, $L_{\text{obs}}\rightarrow 0$ and thus all object lengths and distances tend to zero, implying obstacles would get closer to you as you approach the speed of light.